# Как правильно расставить якоря в UI для линии

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-ui

Создал линию с помощью компонента Image, установил Height в 1 unit, как правильно расставить якоря для неё?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Зависит от того, где эта линия находится и для чего она нужна. Если просто горизонтальная линия на весь экран, то ставите якоря по X у краев, по Y сужаете максимально, выставляете в `RectTransform` `left = 0` `right = 0` `Pos Y = 0` `Height = 1`